# Creating user with uid 1000 on alpine Docker image

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

When I'm trying to create user with `UID=1000` in Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.16

RUN addgroup -g 1000 sail
RUN adduser -g 1000 -u 1000 sail
```

I'm getting error:

```
Step 3/3 : RUN adduser -g 1000 -u 1000 sail
 ---> Running in 0c4ce7e0bddf
adduser: uid '1000' in use
The command '/bin/sh -c adduser -g 1000 -u 1000 sail' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

But if I'm build a container without this stage and look to `/etc/passwd` there is no user with `UID=1000`. So it's exists only while building.

How to create user with `UID=1000` properly in alpine?

Comment: What user-id will you get for sail? Do you happen to have the UID already used in the docker-host?

Comment: A specific numeric user ID in a Dockerfile shouldn't matter, so long as it's not zero.  (The image should normally be runnable on many hosts with different host user IDs.)  Can you pick a different number, or even remove the `-u` option entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, the `adduser` command of Alpine is the [BusyBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) one, so, unlike  the *"regular"* `adduser`, here are its help page:

```
BusyBox v1.35.0 (2022-08-01 15:14:44 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: adduser [OPTIONS] USER [GROUP]

Create new user, or add USER to GROUP

        -h DIR          Home directory
        -g GECOS        GECOS field
        -s SHELL        Login shell
        -G GRP          Group
        -S              Create a system user
        -D              Don't assign a password
        -H              Don't create home directory
        -u UID          User id
        -k SKEL         Skeleton directory (/etc/skel)
```

You can easily go through it, running the command:

```bash
docker run -ti --rm alpine:3.16 adduser
```

The important part of information here are:

```
-g GECOS        GECOS field
-G GRP          Group
```

Where you can see that, a group, in BusyBox `adduser` requires your to be added with the option `G`, in capital letter, and that the option `g` in lowercase if for something else.

The option allows you to add a group, and not a GID, so you'll need the command:

```bash
RUN adduser -G sail -u 1000 sail
```

---

Furthermore, if you run that command, the shell will prompt you to fill in a password. You will need to skip this with the `D` option:

```
-D              Don't assign a password
```

And so, your *Dockerfile* ends up being:

```bash
FROM alpine:3.16

RUN addgroup -g 1000 sail \
    && adduser -G sail -u 1000 sail -D
```

*<sub>Note that it is always a good idea, in Docker, to reduce as much as possible the number of layers you are creating by running subsequent `RUN` instruction, for further reading on this, [see here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers).</sub>*